# Make what a user puts in an input box automatically appear in another box

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a three input fields. I am trying to do a basic equation with the three inputs and have the result appear into another box. I do not understand how to make the result appear in that box. Any help please?

```
  <input type="text" id="miles" placeholder="miles">
  <input type="text" id="minutes" placeholder="minutes">
  <input type="text" id="tip" placeholder="tip">

  <input type="output" value="total" id='total'>
```

Comment: What do you have at the moment?

Comment: -1 you should know that your question is too broad, what input can be inserted in the input field? basic equation? there is not very clear

Comment: im just looking for a general answer. i want something like miles*2 + minutes + tip = total. either way idc about the math right now.. more about the ability for the output to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your tag is javascript, i assume your looking for an jquery/js solution.

I will give you an jquery solution:

First of all you have 3 input fields. I assume these are fields for calculating something.
With jQuery it could be done like this.

It checks if input field 1 or input field 2 has been changed. If there has been a change it will execute the function and give input field 3 the value of the other 2 combined.

```
$('.field1, .field2').change(function () {
var valfield1 = $('.field1').val();
var valfield2 = $('.field2').val();
var valfield3 = valfield1 + valfield2;
$('field3').val(valfield3);
});
```

You could even make this live editing, by replacing "change" with "keyup".

Comment: exactly what I wanted. thank you.

Comment: one problem... i have essentially exactly what you wrote. lets say  field one was 4 and field two was 5.. it shows up as 45, not 9. how do i solve this?

Comment: You need to convert the values to integers before performing arithmetic on them.

Comment: how do i do that? just a direction to head would be great..